# How to obtain token from "secondary" app from FirebaseApp.initializeApp()

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to initialize two FCM server in a single FCM client app.
First app is initialize with default name which is "[DEFAULT]" and second app is initialize with name "secondary".
Since in FirebaseApp it is compulsory to name one app as "[DEFAULT]".

After initialization I trying to obtain token value from both app but I am only receiving token from the [DEFAULT] app. Secondary app is returning null while querying for the token.

//Default app initialization:

```
FirebaseOptions.Builder defaultBuilder = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
            .setApplicationId("[applicationID]")
            .setApiKey("[apikey]")
            .setDatabaseUrl("[url]")
            .setStorageBucket("[storageBucket]");
FirebaseApp defaultapp =FirebaseApp.initializeApp   (this,defaultBuilder.build());
```

//secondary app initialization:

```
 FirebaseOptions.Builder defaultBuilder1 = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
            .setApplicationId("[applicationID]")
            .setApiKey("[apikey]")
            .setDatabaseUrl("[url]")
            .setStorageBucket("[storageBucket]");
 FirebaseApp myapp = FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this,defaultBuilder1.build(),"secondary");
```

//getting token for default app:

```
Log.d(TAG, "Default app token: " + FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance
(defaultapp).getToken());
```

//getting token for secondary app:

```
Log.d(TAG, "Secondary app token: " + FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance
(myapp).getToken());
```

'
Here Default app is returning proper token value but Secondary app is returning null, incase if we switch the FirebaseOptions for both app then still I am only able to get token from the server which is initialized as DEFAULT.

Comment: Got the answer..I just have to get the token in different thread